# How to test if an item is left justified?

Tags: cobol

I can't figure out how to test if a read in item is left justified or not. For example if I have a `WORD-IN PIC X(8)`, how do I create a test that tests if there are any blanks or "b's" read in.

```
Word read in = _____CAT
WORD-IN then equals bbbbbCAT
```

Could I test for leading b's? Doing this for data validation. There would be a random amount of leading b's if there are, but just one would make it not left justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
05   word-in.
   07 word-in-x      pic x(01) occurs 8.


if word-in-x(1) is equal to space ...
```

Comment: whats the 07? i've only seen 01 05 and 08 and 88 before

Comment: Any level 01..49 is valid. 66,77,88 have special functions. Use `10` if you like - it's not relevant. The object is to set up a redefinition of the item `word-in`

Answer (score 1):

Some variants:

```
01  word-in.
    05  FILLER                          PIC X.
        88  word-in-data-not-left-just  VALUE SPACE.
    05  FILLER                          PIC X(7).

IF word-in-data-not-left-just
    ....
END-IF
```

Defining the data to isolate the first byte, and using an 88 on it so that the reader knows what it means.

```
01   word-in.
     05 FILLER                          pic x(01) occurs 8.
        88  word-in-data-not-left-just  VALUE SPACE.

if word-in-data-not-left-just ( 1 ) 
    ....
END-IF
```

As Magoo's, the 88 could go exactly on their solution as well, but no need to give the data a name, just the 88.

```
01  word-in                             PIC X(8).

IF word-in ( 1 : 1 ) EQUAL TO SPACE
    ....
END-IF
```

Reference modification. When encountering, just call around the office "what does it mean when the first byte of word-in is space?" Someone's sure to know. If not, you get the extra enjoyment of having to work out the intention before you know if you need to know.

The code generated from all of the above will (IBM Enterprise COBOL)/should be the same, so choice of which is for human understanding, the compiler doesn't care. It does what it is told, even if it takes a human more time to work out what that is, depending on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSPECT statement. For leading spaces use:

```
01  WS-CNT    PIC S9(5)  COMP-3.

INSPECT WORD-IN TALLYING WS-CNT FOR LEADING SPACES
```

To count trailing spaces you can:

```
Inspect function reverse(word-in) tallying ws-cnt for leading spaces
```

The variable ws-cnt will have the number of spaces.

Comment: To find out if there is one leading space (same for trailing) you'd fire up INSPECT? FUNCTION REVERSE and INSPECT?